# How to speed up AngularJS rendering with big scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

I'm developping an angular app right now for my company, but I reached a point where the app became extremely slow so I tried tunning it by using onetimebind everywhere I can, track by ...but it's faster to load at first but still laggy, it is composed of a pretty much huge nested objects, I've counted the total number of objects, it starts at 680 and can go up to +6000 for normal use of the app, oh yeah I should precise that the app is generating a form and pretty much +90% of the objects in the scope belongs to an input and are updated each time the client click(radio) keyup/change(text).

It also have like 5/6 arrays composed of objects and the array gets bigger/smaller accodring to the clients choice, and that's where it gets laggy, each time I add an object to the array, it takes like a second to render it, so I tried using nested controllers thinking that if the child of an object is updated Angular will render only this child and not all the others, but somehow the app got even slower and laggier :s (it's a bit faster when I use ng-show instead of ng-if but the memory used jumps from ~50Mb to ~150Mb)

I should also precise that the form is in a wizard style, and not all the inputs are displayed at once, the number of inputs that are displayed are between 10%-20% of the total inputs

Has anyone encountred this problem before? does anyone know how to deal with big scopes?

Comment: "how to deal with big scopes" - separate them into nested elements (controllers, directives with isolated scope, etc)

Comment: Due to the 2-way data binding in Angular if you have 1,000's of objects the watching for changes will slow things down.

Comment: do all of the items need two way binding, or do they just need to be rendered once? There are some tricks for that

Comment: One thing you could do is to use `ng-if` at the wizard-page level - this should cut off the number of watchers to 10%-20%. Other things that contribute to slow performance are function watchers, like `{{generateData()}}` - make sure that if you have those, then they should not be much more than a simple getter - for example, no for-loops there. Lastly, make sure you don't have deep-watchers (`$scope.$watch(..., true)`) or large nested objects

Comment: "It also have like 5/6 arrays composed of objects and the array gets bigger/smaller according to the clients choice, and that's where it gets laggy, each time I add an object to the array, it takes like a second to render it" -- If your business logic is taking more time to (i.e. find,filter,search) generate new objects than in that case you can use loadsh.js,linq.js etc. according to your requirements, to generate and deal with it quickly.Thus,it will makes your new objects building fast and 
automatically your binding works smoothly.

Comment: Also you can use caching mechanism in angular when it requires to get data at places.

Comment: @scunliffe I've slimmed down the number of watchers to 70 on init, and goes around ~200-300 in normal use. So I don't this that it's watchers who are slowing down my app

Comment: @Chase That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but somehow the rendering is still slow when showing the children of a child if ng-if is true

Comment: @Jorg I already made sure that only the inputs use models (two way bingin)

Comment: @NewDev Check for ng-if. Check for few watchers. for the large nested objects well I think it's pretty large, here the full [scope](http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/1d921b). Note that json.contract_architecture is used the main controller, for the other each one has it's controller (example: options_wrapper -> OptionCtrl)

Comment: @road2victory I'll definitelfy give that a try right now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "check"... and even if you have this json, what I meant is that it is not a good idea to have a deep-watch: `$scope.$watch("largeJson", true)`. Also, you json seems to have HTML templates there... so, I suspect you might have something wonky there with how you are compiling these templates.... The question is really too broad and light on specifics to give you a good answer.

Comment: @NewDev I'm not using the templates right now. I mean that I've already done it by "Check"

Comment: I dealt that with replacing angular rendering with my [own renderer](https://github.com/S-YOU/doTA)  - basic concept is - write your own angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Sad to say, but that's intrinsic of the view rendering in angular.
An update in the model triggers a potential redraw of the entire view. No matter if you have elements hidden or not. The two way data binding can really kill performances. You can consider evaluate if you need to render the view only once, in that case there are optimizations, but I'm assuming that your form change dynamically, therefore a 2 way data binding is necessary.

You can try to work around this limitation but encapsulate sub part of the entire MVC. In this way a contained controllers only update the specific view associated to that scope.

You may want to consider using react (that has as first goal to address exactly your use case)

Have a look at this blog post for a comparison of the rendering pipeline between angular and react Js.

http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/